# bubble up events and html/dom structure?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

Consider this html :

```
   <table>
      <tr>
        <td>
         <input type="button"/>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

And this js code :

```
$(":button").click(function (){alert('b')});
$("table").click(function (){alert('t')});
```

This will alert `b` and **then** `t`. because  we pressed on button which then **bubble up** the event to the table.

So according to the chain of events the html tree should look like this:

```
+-------------------------------+
|                               | //table   
+------+------------------+-----+
       |                  |  //tr 
       +------------------+
            |        |   //td
            +--------+
              |    |    //button
              +----+
```

Which means the event  bubble **up** ( as they say - from bottom to top).

**Question :**

I know that the dom tree is arranged as my drawing (as a tree), **but** does the html "tree" is arranged on the opposite direction  ( flip vertical) ? because I see a lot of examples that shows a tower being built from bottom to top  :

I mean :

```
     _        //button
   _____      //td
  ________    // tr
_____________ //table
```

But here , bubble up event  - should be bubble "down" becuase as we saw , the button runs first...

Comment: Where did you see the inverted tree? The events bubble *up*.

Comment: @bfavaretto here for example (http://ils.indiana.edu/faculty/hrosenba/www/Workshops/CSS/Demo/cssstructure.html) and here (http://www.phpeveryday.com/articles/jQuery-Event-Object-P957.html) I can give a 1000 more

Comment: I see nested boxes in that link, and they look like a regular tree to me.

Comment: @bfavaretto look here http://javascript.info/tutorial/bubbling-and-capturing

Comment: That's the same! See the second picture, it's an inverted pyramid, as in your first example with the triangular shape pointing down. Anyway, that's probably a matter of personal point of view, just keep in mind it's usually said that events travel "down" during capture, then bubble "up".

Comment: @bfavaretto yes. the capture is the missing part. (then it bubbles) but still it seems that the html tree is upside down)

Comment: You are really over thinking this :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> does the html "tree" is arranged on the opposite direction (flip vertical)? because I see a lot of examples that shows a tower being built from bottom to top

It's a DOM tree, not a DOM tower. In computer science the convention is to draw [trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_structure) with their root at the top and their leafs at the bottom.

The terms "up" and "down" make more sense if you think of the DOM as *nested* (which it indeed is) instead of just being connected in some direction. Then you will dive *down* into the more detailed structures, and bubble back *up* to the outermost layers.

For a definitive answer, read the [*Event dispatch and DOM event flow* chapter](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#event-flow) in the W3 specification.

Comment: Bergi - I did mention the difference when I said in my question : "dom tree". but the thing which confused me wast the html "towers" which I see in many sites - which made me confused about the bubble up term.

Comment: [These graphics](http://javascript.info/tutorial/bubbling-and-capturing) don't show a tower, but an inverted pyramid. Like [this one](http://ils.indiana.edu/faculty/hrosenba/www/Workshops/CSS/Demo/cssstructure.html) it is very confusing (if not wrong) to show the boxes outside of their parents. In [that article](http://www.phpeveryday.com/articles/jQuery-Event-Object-P957.html) they're properly nested.

Answer (score 2):

it's just called [`event bubbling`](http://mdn.beonex.com/en/DOM/event.bubbles.html) or [`event propagation`](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html), the direction does not really matter...

But it's often called `bubble up` because they represent the tree in the following way:

- document

  - div
  - table

    - tr

      - td

        - button
  - p
  - div

    - p

      - span

and thus like that, it bubbles 'up' again.... until it reaches the root.

Note how the tree representation follows how you actually write the HTML structure itself.

Comment: bubble ( to me) means up

Comment: @RoyiNamir Right. And it does matter because that's what your question is. Anyway, I wouldn't take the Indiana University site too seriously. Just stick with your original idea.

Comment: @MrLister I did not. also , just search google images for event bubble. ( i took that link because it has nice visualization. also google images search)

Comment: Well, because we think of air bubbles in water, but bubbles could also come down, like balloons with cold gas who fall to the ground. or soap bubbles with one of those blow thingies :)

Comment: @NickyDeMaeyer dont try to invent obvious things :-). the bubble means up thats why the analogy is for - to remember it. there is a reason for it. the capture ( now that i see it) means down while bubbles means up. I would search it in w3c.

Comment: I'm not inventing, you say bubble means up, but that's just your perception, because you are a programmer. It is by no means `up` by definition... So you are the inventor here, sir.

Comment: @NickyDeMaeyer http://javascript.info/tutorial/bubbling-and-capturing    ...are they inventors also ?

Comment: I'm not talking about javascript, I'm just saying that physically bubbles do not **always** go up, so you should not assume that without thinking it through... and thus bubble is **not a synonym** for **up** as you keep saying.

Answer (score 2):

Web browsers do not have auricular balance mechanisms, and are therefore utterly ignorant of the concepts of "up" and "down".  Whether a tree structure is illustrated as expanding upwards on the page (or screen) or downwards is purely a matter of convenience to support some idea.

We think of "bubbling up" probably because we also think of the "depth" of DOM nodes in the tree.  If a child node like your button is at a particular depth, then its chain of parents are at lesser depths. As an event is handed to event handlers at decreasing depths, well, that's reminiscent of ascending from deep water to shallow, like bubbles.

Again, however, that concept of "depth" is just a colloquial mnemonic to help us keep the structure of the DOM clear in our heads.  An isomorphic set of terms would work just as well once we all got used to them. For example, if we had a common word in English for the experience of a baby squirrel tumbling down out of a tree, bumping against branches on the way, we could use that instead of "bubble" (assuming we could handle the violent imagery of bruised baby squirrels).

Comment: So, are "event listeners" some kind of hearing aid devices?

Comment: @bfavaretto I prefer to think of "event listeners" as "cat whiskers" personally

Comment: That's a nice analogy!

Comment: @Pointy So when I click on an element( in my question) --- As a POV to the `iexplore.exe browser` program -- in which element did i press first? button or table ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir: [table then button then table](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#event-flow).

Comment: @Bergi that's what the spec says - old IE didn't do the "capture" phase, right?  I suppose IE10 might. I've never seen use made of the capture phase event flow.

Answer (score 1):

The event first goes *down* the tree during the capture phase, then bubble *up*. You can intercept them during capture with the following, which alerts "t" first:

```
var btn = document.getElementById('btn');
var tbl = document.getElementById('tbl');

btn.addEventListener('click', function(){
    alert('b')
}, true);

tbl.addEventListener('click', function(){
    alert('t')
}, true);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ajx8q/

Note that although I say "up" and "down" here, they are just conventions (see [Pointy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18083193/825789)).

Answer (score 1):

It's just how the method is named. It's mostly conceptual anyway and doesn't matter at all to how the method actually works.

For example, if you take any hierarchical structure, you will always have the base or the parent nodes at the top of the structure. (Think of file structures, ancestry trees..)

So if you want an event to propogate to the parent node in the hierarchy, you will have it (conceptually) move upwards.

(It doesn't matter though really how you visualize your hierarchy.)